# Writeline String.format not compleating last value. vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string.format

I am trying to write an xml file ussing a little less conventional method, Just for those wondering there's a long story too why I am doing this. The real point is though that I cant seem to get the Tag named  to write its value to the resulting XML file and I cant fuigureout why... could somebody help me with this...

The code as follows...

```
    Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem2.Click

    'define a save dialog
    Dim save_file As New SaveFileDialog

    'give its extension...
    save_file.RestoreDirectory = True
    save_file.InitialDirectory = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & " \ LIBRARY"
    save_file.Filter = "xml files (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    save_file.FilterIndex = 1

    ''create a datatable
    'Dim my_datatable As New DataTable

    'if ok click
    If save_file.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

        Using writer As New IO.StreamWriter(save_file.FileName)
            writer.WriteLine("<COMPELATION>")
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
                If Not row.IsNewRow Then
                    writer.WriteLine(String.Format(vbCrLf & vbTab & "<Data>" & vbCrLf & vbTab & vbTab & "<DEF>{0}</DEF>" & vbCrLf & vbTab & vbTab & "<HGT>{1}</HGT>" & vbCrLf & vbTab & vbTab & "<LEN>{2}</LEN>" & vbCrLf & vbTab & vbTab & "<WDT>{3}</WDT>" & vbCrLf & vbTab & vbTab & "<THK>{4}</THK>" & vbCrLf & vbTab & vbTab & "<AN1>{5}</AN1>" & vbCrLf & vbTab & vbTab & "<AN2>{6}</AN2>" & vbCrLf & vbTab & vbTab & "<MAT>{7}</MAT>" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "</Data>",
                                   row.Cells(0).Value,
                                   row.Cells(1).Value,
                                   row.Cells(2).Value,
                                   row.Cells(3).Value,
                                   row.Cells(4).Value,
                                   row.Cells(5).Value,
                                   row.Cells(6).Value,
                                   row.Cells(7).Value))
                End If
            Next
            writer.WriteLine("</COMPELATION>")
            writer.Close()
        End Using

        Dim result1 As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to use this file as the default library?", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

        If result1 = DialogResult.Yes Then
            'Set the new file as the default XML...
            My.Settings.DEFAULTXML = save_file.FileName

            'Reload and bind the data source...
            Me.Refresh()

        Else
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you're getting errors what are they? Or what behaviour are you expecting and what do you get. Sorry but saying "it's not working" isnt enough.

Comment: No errors, just <MAT>{7}</MAT> which is getting its imput from row.Cells(7).Value) is not doing anything... all other string.format parts are working??

Comment: I've just run that line with my own data, and It seems to work just fine - Is the data in the cell valid? What datatype is cell 7?

Comment: Well I'm assued by what I see that the resulting XML has the last <MAT></MAT> with no value inbetween the tags... 100% sure

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint at that line and hovering your mouse over the data to see what is in that cell?